# VBA excel - Activate method fails when file opens from a network folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with several macros. I want to get some things done when the file opens. I use the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    pass = "mits"
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q2:S16").NumberFormat = "General"
    Call prostasiaON(True)
End Sub
```

This code is written in 'This_Workbook module', `pass` is a public variable declared in module 1 and `prostasiaON(mode as Boolean)` is a Sub that does some other things.

When my file is in a local drive it opens as it should. If I copy my file in a network drive and try to open it, it throws a

Run-time error '1004': Method Activate of class Worksheet failed.

in the second line. Can anybody please explain why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Edit: before throwing this error, excel asks me if I want to allow edit of this file and I choose yes.

Comment: is your sheet protected ?

Comment: No it is not protected.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to `Activate` the worksheet? You don't need to do that. What you are attempting to do with `Worksheets(1).Range("Q2:S16").NumberFormat = "General"` will work without having to activate the sheet. Also, qualifying your sheet is a much better approach through VBA then attempting to `Activate` or `Select` it

Comment: This is what I want the user to see when he opens the file. That's why.

Comment: I would try... workbooks ("workbook name")... and check if its better then this workbook

Comment: That's probably one of the very few times where I would do the same :). I suspect you are getting this error because your workbook is open but worksheets are not loaded (which is suggestive of why its working from local drive and not on a network drive). Try getting a count of your sheets in `Workbook_Open()` sub and then check for the sheet you want to activate before you attempt to activate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 's what solved the problem. I 'm posting this as a reference for future seekers.

In this post I got a solution that could match:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f4c993e6-e226-4e39-8964-8f3a4b3dcf21/protected-view-for-networked-drives?forum=officeitproprevious

The sence is similar to Variantus's answer above.

If you know for sure that the network drive that your file is into *is indeed a trusted location*, here 's the steps of the solution:

1. open Ιnternet Εxplorer, click Τools/Internet Options and select the tab Security.
2. I selected Local Intranet because that 's the case.
3. hit Sites/Advanced.
4. in the first field write the path of the network drive or folder that your file is into (and you want to set is as a secure location).
5. hit the Add button and you 're ready.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the question whether you want to allow editing because the code won't actually run until you have agreed although the workbook appears loaded. You won't have the problem if you can set trust and permissions so as to avoid the incomplete opening of the workbook and the question whether you want to allow editing.
If you are unable to avoid this question you will also be unable to avoid the error that occurs on `Activate`. So, the thing I do is to add `On Error Resume Next` and live without Worksheets(1) being activated under the circumstances you described.